# Bind can't resolve the domain (only forward)

Tags: dns, fedora, bind

I followed [this tutorial](https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-with-bind/) as well as I could on my Fedora 31 box. I have a setup with a router running on 192.168.1.1 and two machines with fixed IP addresses: mando (192.168.1.2) and carbon (192.168.1.3). I want to make mando a DNS server.

I configured my new DNS server (mando) like this:

```
// /etc/named.conf
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.2; };
        // ...
        allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24; };
        // ...
};
// ...
zone "mando.intranet" IN {
  type master;
  file "forward.intranet";
  allow-update { none; };
};
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
  type master;
  file "reverse.intranet";
  allow-update { none; };
};
// ...
```

Then, as per instructions, I created the zone files with the configuration below:

```
$ pwd
/var/named

$ sudo cat forward.intranet
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN mando.intranet.
@   IN  SOA     mando.intranet. root.intranet. (
        2011071001  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@       IN  NS          mando.intranet.
@       IN  A   192.168.1.2
mando.intranet  IN  A   192.168.1.2
carbon.intranet IN  A   192.168.1.3

$ sudo cat reverse.intranet 
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     mando.intranet. root.intranet. (
        2011071001  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@       IN  NS          mando.intranet.
@       IN  PTR         intranet.
mando           IN  A   192.168.1.2
carbon          IN  A   192.168.1.3
2       IN  PTR         mando.intranet.
3       IN  PTR         carbon.intranet.
```

I also set the DNS server to 192.168.1.2 on both hosts' /etc/resolv.conf and (re)started bind on the DNS server.

The result:

- Both servers can resolve mando, forward and reverse.
- Both servers can resolve internet websites, forward and reverse.
- Both servers can resolve carbon *only in reverse*.
- Both servers ***fail to resolve carbon*** (192.168.1.3).

I've looked everywhere but couldn't figure out what I may be missing. Disclaimer: this is my first time setting up a DNS server.

Some more output for clarification:

```
[mando ~]$ dig carbon.intranet

; <<>> DiG 9.11.10-RedHat-9.11.10-1.fc29 <<>> carbon.intranet
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 138
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: fe8f986e44b3c029e54805715e8fc6504fb2c9b9451b2464 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;carbon.intranet.               IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       10750   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020040903 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 09 20:05:20 CDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 147

[mando ~]$ nslookup 192.168.1.3
3.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa        name = carbon.intranet.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you **don't have a zone** that would contain `carbon.intranet`. The only one that you've defined in your named.conf is "mando.intranet" – and that's different.

Zone names are important. They're not merely labels – they tell the nameserver which *suffix* this zonefile will handle, i.e. you allowed it to resolve anything that ends with `.mando.intranet` only. And the "carbon.intranet" domain name clearly doesn't end with that.

If you wanted to handle *all* names which end with `.intranet`, then you should have used:

```
zone "intranet" IN {
```

(And yes, you should update $ORIGIN within the zone file accordingly.)

Second, you **didn't fully follow zonefile syntax rules** about writing down domain names. The main purpose of the $ORIGIN parameter is that it's automatically *appended* to all domain names which are "not fully qualified" – i.e. those which do not end with a dot.

Let's say you've already fixed the zone name and origin to be just "intranet", as written in the previous section. Let's say you have this zone:

```
$ORIGIN intranet
carbon.intranet IN  A   192.168.1.3
```

In a zonefile, because the record name does not end with a dot, it *always* gets the $ORIGIN appended to it – so the actual domain you defined is `carbon.intranet.intranet.`!

The correct way to define `carbon.intranet.` is either one of those:

```
$ORIGIN intranet
carbon IN  A   192.168.1.3
```

or

```
carbon.intranet. IN  A   192.168.1.3
```

In the second case, notice that the name ends with a `.` so it doesn't use $ORIGIN at all – you're directly specifying the full name.

Comment: That worked! I was getting the nameserver mixed up with the zone name in my head.